# Call destructor of service when an exception raised in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, exception

I have a WCF service that use Exceptions to returns wrong results. for example when a argument of method is wrong an exception raised and send a exception to a client and client catch that exception and show its message. I use FaultException too. but the problem is the destructor of service class doesn't called when an exception raised. I must dispose the repository in the destructor when exceptions occured. how can I do it?

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private AccountReposiory _accountReposiory;

    public TestService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started!");

        _accountReposiory = new AccountReposiory();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        //Exception Occurred!;

        throw new Exception("Some Exception");

        //...
    }

    ~TestService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");

        _accountReposiory.Dipose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use destructor , because .net C# is managed language

GC class automatically call when then any class initialized,

use ....,

```
try{

   Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred!");

}catch(Execption ex){

     return;

} 


try{

   Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred!");

}catch{



}
```

block to solve this problem. don't use destructor. I think it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Doing cleanups is always a good thing, except when not needed, and if it adds your code a lot of overhead.

In your case, I suppose you want to make sure the class is destroyed after use because of used non managed systems resources. In this case maybe [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264746/wcf-service-and-idisposable-do-i-clean-up-managed-objects) will help you:

If you are not using non managed system resources, then you can leave the clean up to the garbage collector.